# Changing the way text is displayed for QLineEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.10

I would like to change the text display of some `QLineEdit`'s.
The text should be displayed as a euro amount.

**QLineEdits do not seem to be the appropriate choice for such a display. I therefore adapt the code to QDoubleSpinBox. With `self.setButtonSymbols(QDoubleSpinBox.NoButtons)` the graphical representation of the QDoubleSpinBoxes is identical to that of QLineEdits**

Briefly so that the context is clear:

I have several QTableWidgets in which I use custom delegates such as:

```
class EuroDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def displayText(self, value, locale):
        if value is not None:
            value = float(value)
            return locale.toCurrencyString(value, '€', 2)
        else:
            return super().displayText(value, locale)
```

to display the text as a euro amount.

Some QLineEdits also contain euro amounts and I want them to "feel" as similar as possible. Therefore I changed those **QLineEdits** to **QDoubleSpinBoxes**.

As a result, some of the desired properties are quickly achieved.
<strike>striked items</strike> on the list are already implemented in the code snippet below:

1. <strike>'€' is displayed after the amount.</strike>
2. <strike>'€' should not be part of the `LineEdit.text()`.</strike>
3. <strike>The QLineEdits behave similarly to the delegates: When the QLineEdit is focused, the "€" character disappears, when it loses focus, it then reappears.</strike>
4. <strike>Clicking/focusing the QDoubleSpinbox should select the complete content.</strike>
5. The QDoubleSpinBox should set the "," automatically. Entries such as: "0050" should ideally be displayed directly on entry (before the 'Enter' key) as: "00,50" and after the 'Enter' key (as default with the QDoubleSpinBox) "0,50".
   The same would also apply to entries such as: "-1050" => "-10,50", whereby entries such as "99" + Enter should continue to produce "99,00". The box should therefore recognize that the input would exceed or fall below its "min/max range" and then automatically set the decimal point. (In my country, the separation is made using "," (=> "Euros,Cents") and the QDoubleSpinBox already respects this.)

Edit:
Further explanation to 5.): Since I may have expressed myself unclear:
I would like that inputs that would fall above or below the setrange are not blocked, but that instead a comma is added if possible (check if there is already a comma?) and the input is continued instantly in the decimal point area.

A code snippet to play around with:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QDoubleSpinBox, QLineEdit, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

class EuroDoubleSpinBox(QDoubleSpinBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setButtonSymbols(QDoubleSpinBox.NoButtons)
        self.normalSuffix = ''
        self.currencySuffix = ' €'
        self.setSuffix(self.currencySuffix)

    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        self.setSuffix(self.normalSuffix)
        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.selectAll)
        super().focusInEvent(event)

    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
        self.setSuffix(self.currencySuffix)
        super().focusOutEvent(event)


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.pushbutton = QPushButton('Print DoubleSpinBox Value')
        self.lineedit = QLineEdit() # added for focus toggling
        self.doubleSpinBox = EuroDoubleSpinBox()
        self.doubleSpinBox.setRange(-99.99, 99.99)
        self.doubleSpinBox.setSingleStep(0.01)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        layout.addWidget(self.doubleSpinBox)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushbutton)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.pushbutton.clicked.connect(lambda: print(self.doubleSpinBox.cleanText()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 100)
    window.setWindowTitle('Euro DoubleSpinBox')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm using python 3.10.13 and PyQt5 5.15.9

Comment: Use a QDoubleSpinBox subclass and change the [`prefix()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html#prefix-prop) whenever it receives/loses focus. You don't need to change the code whenever the ui file is changed as long as you're not trying to edit the pyuic generated files (which you shouldn't), and you can use widget promotion for the custom line edits.

Comment: Thank you very much, your input has (as always) helped me a lot. I still couldn't implement one of the desired effects (regex). Slightly off topic: Since you mentioned pyuic (and I don't want to get 1mio downvotes for asking): Have you changed your mind regarding LoadUi vs. pyuic?

Comment: I still prefer the loadUi approach, but there are situations for which using pyuic may be advisable. That said, you've expanded the question, and now it's not really clear what you actually need. I suggest you to take your time to rephrase the post, clarify which are the aspects you're not able to achieve and remove irrelevant aspects (the part about Designer is not relevant anymore and there's no point in leaving it there, since it's not part of the problem).

Comment: I have now deleted what I thought was necessary. Although I now use QDoubleSpinBoxes, I think it makes sense to record the development starting with QLineEdits. Others might benefit in the future. (If I had found such an entry, I would never have experimented with QLineEdits for so long).

Comment: About the selection on focus, it's expected: the user expects to be able to directly click between characters and start editing at that specific point (the tab focus instead works as you want, by automatically selecting the text when "tabbed in"); while your solution works, it's not the expected convention, forcing users to click *twice*. Besides that, you're still not explaining the problem: QDoubleSpinBox internally manages the validation only allowing insertion of valid characters (numbers, decimal separator and possibly the negative sign). Why do you want to set a different validator?

Comment: I agree, at least in part. Setting such a validator is perhaps not the best step (especially since the incorrect entries are already well intercepted). Therefore, I am changing my desired behavior a bit. See Edit.

Comment: @musicamante I would agree with your behavior of tabs and clicks IF there were many elements in the form (or at all) that were designed for keyboard input. Apart from the dateEdits (previous question), the forms mostly consist of comboboxes, checkboxes etc.. So I would be surprised if the user would tab through.

Comment: Well, it's a matter of habit. I use keyboard navigation *a lot* (and I know I'm not a rare exception) even when there are just a few text fields, and the first thing I tried when I run your code was indeed to use tab. You should never underestimate keyboard navigation, even in a period where most people doesn't know about that and is more inclined to use mouse and touch gestures; nonetheless, as said, selection on focus-click is *not* the expected behavior, it's the exact opposite, and many users may find that choice actually annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QAbstractSpinBox subclasses provide a [`validate()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractspinbox.html#validate) function that calls an internal validator, similarly to what `validate()` of QValidator does.

The solution is to override that function according to your needs.

For such a simple requirement (add the decimal point when the third digit is being typed), the following should probably suffice:

```py
class EuroDoubleSpinBox(QDoubleSpinBox):
    ...
    def validate(self, text, pos):
        if 2 < len(text.lstrip('-')) < 5:
            if text.isdecimal():
                p = 2
            elif text.startswith('-') and text[1:].isdecimal() and len(text) > 3:
                p = 3
            else:
                return super().validate(text, pos)
            value = float('{}.{}'.format(text[:p], text[p:]))
            if self.minimum() <= value <= self.maximum():
                return (
                    QValidator.Acceptable, 
                    text[:p] + QLocale().decimalPoint() + text[p:], 
                    pos + 1
                )
        return super().validate(text, pos)
```

The procedure is the following:

1. check that the length of the typed text (without leading minus signs) is 3 or 4 characters;
2. if the text is decimal (only characters in the `0-9` range, similar to `\d?` for regex), assume that the decimal point goes after the second digit;
3. if the text begins with a minus sign and the following characters represent a decimal *and* the length at least 3 characters, set the position of the decimal point after the *third* digit;
4. if 2 and 3 fail, return the default validation;
5. construct the possible float value by inserting the decimal *dot* after the second or third position;
6. if the value is between the minimum/maximum range of the spin box, return a `QValidator.Acceptable`, the text with the decimal point defined by the locale, and augment the cursor position by one;
7. as final fall back, return the default validation;

The above should work fine for almost any case, including pasting from keyboard. More fine tuning might be required if you also want to support pasting float values using the dot as decimal point while the system uses a different symbol (like in your case).